# height issue for 'tabs' widget as a child of other widget, flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to have tabs layout similar to Twitter profile page, where tabs layout shows in the middle of the page. To start with, I have created a basic layout with column as parent and other widgets including tabs as child. Code looks similar to below

```dart
    Column(
    children: [
        Text("some text");
        
        //some image widget
        
        ElevatedButton(
            style: style,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("click me"),
          );
        
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Flexible( //without flexible wrapper, it throws unbounded height issue.
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.pink,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.pink,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(child: Text("Tweets")),
                    Tab(child: Text("Tweets and replies")),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: new TabBarView(children: [
                    //some widgets here
                  ],),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
    ]
    )
```

but with above code issue is that, tabs layout doesn't fill remaining space, but just fill some fixed space.

[image]

i want to cover the remaining space with tabs, till bottom. if i remove remaining children of parent column and just keep tab, it fill all available space as expected.

Comment: In my case, it is working, I wrapped the child with a container for test purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you face any issue, do `flutter clean` and restart

**Result**

[image: output]

**Test widget**

```
class SWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("some text"),

          //some image widget

          ElevatedButton(
            // style: style,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("click me"),
          ),

          DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Flexible(
              //without flexible wrapper, it throws unbounded height issue.
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.pink,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.pink,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(child: Text("Tweets")),
                      Tab(child: Text("Tweets and replies")),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: new TabBarView(
                      children: [
                        //some widgets here
                        Container(
                          child: Text("item 1"),
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text("item 2"),
                              Text("item 2"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          color: Colors.deepOrange,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it does solve the issue.